# SVG linear gradient dont work in ie11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, linear-gradients

I have this gradient code in an SVG-File:

```
<linearGradient id="SVGRD" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-243.3" y1="1257.3" x2="-242.3" y2="1257.3" gradientTransform="matrix(-64.7347 -199.2328 -199.2328 64.7347 234813.9219 -129743.9844)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B3B3B3"/>
  <stop  offset="0.45" style="stop-color:#B3B3B3;stop-opacity:0.22"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B3B3B3;stop-opacity:0"/>
</linearGradient>
<path style="fill:url(#SVGRD);" d="M142.7,133L105,18.5H0V133H142.7z"/>
```

It dont seem to work in IE11. The path is rendered without gradient and fill color only.

The SVG is implemented as an image. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient has no vector (x1=x2 and y1=y2). According to the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradients) this degenerate case should result in a single colour which is the last stop colour.

If that's what IE is displaying then it's entirely correct to do so. It's certainly what Firefox will display given such a gradient.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!

Comment: In my particular case, the `linearGradient` for two colors did not have the second `stop-color` defined, and due to that IE11 rendered the second color as black, which broke the expected rendering. Although this answer did not quite resolve the issue, the linked document provided the necessary information to deal with the issue. Will read it in more detail.