# SVG not displaying correctly in IE / Edge

Tags: image, svg

I have an SVG that was provided to me by a designer. It was created in and exported from Illustrator using `File > Export > As SVG`. It should be a circle with a gradient effect but in IE / Edge it just shows as a solid colour.

I have tested this in all other browsers and it works fine.

Is anyone able to see what the problem is?

Here is the SVG content:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="368.7939mm" height="368.7939mm" viewBox="0 0 1045.4 1045.4001">
<defs>
    <style>.a{fill:url(#a);}</style>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="1052.9643" y1="795.8587" x2="1053.9644" y2="795.8587" gradientTransform="matrix(1045.3361, 0, 0, -1045.3359, -1100580.4792, 832495.0613)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#27347f"/>
        <stop offset="0.9997" stop-color="#8c9090"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<title>circle-test</title>
<path class="a" d="M643.8,32.7c-288.7,0-522.7,234-522.7,522.7s234,522.7,522.7,522.7,522.7-234,522.7-522.7S932.5,32.7,643.8,32.7Zm0,837.1c-173.7,0-314.5-140.8-314.5-314.5S470.1,240.8,643.8,240.8,958.3,381.6,958.3,555.3,817.5,869.8,643.8,869.8Z" transform="translate(-121.1 -32.7)"/>
</svg>
```

Note: I'm not using this code inline. This code is placed inside a .svg file which is just included in the page like a normal image file.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615978/svg-linear-gradient-set-as-background-doesnt-work-in-edge-and-ie
 Take a look here if it helps
And something weird for sure its about coordinates in linear gradient. In edge your svg is showing correctly

Comment: ANd here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902420/svg-linear-gradient-dont-work-in-ie11

Comment: https://twitter.com/AmeliasBrain/status/637282554303803392